# AngularJS & Flask : Passing data to html

Tags: angularjs, flask

I am trying to send the data from Flask to AngularJS.

### Server

```
@app.route("/data")
def getDataFromDB():
      cur.execute("select * from employee")
      rows = cur.fetchall()
      columns = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
      result = []
      for row in rows:
          row = dict(zip(columns, row))
          json_row=json.dumps(row)
          result.append(json_row)
          json_response=json.dumps(result)
     response=Response(json_response,content_type='application/json; charset=utf-8')
     response.headers.add('content-length',len(json_response))
     response.status_code=200
     return response
```

### Client

#### maincontroller.js

```
  var app=angular.module('myApp',[]);
  app.controller("MainController", function($scope,$http){

  var done=function(resp){

  $scope.lists=resp.data;
  };
  var fail=function(err){

  };

 $http.get('http://10.62.XX.XX:8083/data')
 .then(done,fail);
```

});

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Learning AngularJS</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"     
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="maincontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

<div id='content'  ng-controller='MainController'>

 <div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat='ele in list'>{{ele}}</li>
    </ul>
 </div>

 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Now, when I access the above code using jsbin.com, I can see my api getting called but nothing is visible on the output screen in jsbin. It is blank.
But when I put the same code in eclipse, I see no api call happening. Do I need to do something more to make angularJS work? I just open the index.html with web browser.

Comment: Do you ever load `mainController.js` on the page?

Comment: <head>
  <title>Learning AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="model.css">
    <script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="maincontroller.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

Comment: And when you look at the network traffic in your browser are `app.js` and `maincontroller.js` being found or are they 404s?

Comment: i donot see 404 but a blank page.

Comment: Yes, but when you hit http://10.62.XX.XX:8083/app.js do you get JavaScript or a 404?

Comment: so my server and client are running with different IPs. Server on ubuntu and client on virtual machine-redhat. and when I do 10.62.XX.XX:8083/app.js, I get 404.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the IP is not your local machine you need to setup [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on the server. I am not familiar with Flask but it looks like there is a [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Cors) that handles this. I also found a function that [sets up CORS for Flask](http://codybonney.com/allow-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-using-flask/).

```
from datetime import timedelta  
from flask import Flask, make_response, request, current_app  
from functools import update_wrapper


def crossdomain(origin=None, methods=None, headers=None, max_age=21600, attach_to_all=True, automatic_options=True):  
    if methods is not None:
        methods = ', '.join(sorted(x.upper() for x in methods))
    if headers is not None and not isinstance(headers, basestring):
        headers = ', '.join(x.upper() for x in headers)
    if not isinstance(origin, basestring):
        origin = ', '.join(origin)
    if isinstance(max_age, timedelta):
        max_age = max_age.total_seconds()

    def get_methods():
        if methods is not None:
            return methods

        options_resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
        return options_resp.headers['allow']

    def decorator(f):
        def wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs):
            if automatic_options and request.method == 'OPTIONS':
                resp = current_app.make_default_options_response()
            else:
                resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))
            if not attach_to_all and request.method != 'OPTIONS':
                return resp

            h = resp.headers

            h['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
            h['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = get_methods()
            h['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = str(max_age)
            if headers is not None:
                h['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = headers
            return resp

        f.provide_automatic_options = False
        return update_wrapper(wrapped_function, f)
    return decorator


@app.route('/')
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def landing():  
    return jsonify(i_am_a='cross domain resource!')

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Comment: +1 for knowing the problem before the OP even made it clear that he was using different origins.

Comment: thanks for the information Andy. so in the server : @app.route("/data")
@cross_origin()
def getDataFromDB():  it does not seem to work for me. Am I missing something?

Comment: so now I have ported my code to the same machine. so have same IPs. still not happening. also when i do http://10.62.XX.XX:8083/app.js, I am getting 404.

Comment: You will have to use developer tools or an http proxy like fiddler to determine whether or not your server is sending back the correct headers (see the Wikipedia link). Also use a more recent version of angular if you can.

Comment: I have installed the latest version of Angular on eclipse. My network doesnot allow install of fiddler. getting no idea what is getting missed.

Comment: Use the developer tools for whatever browser you're using to view http requests. If that's unfamiliar try searching or asking a new question. Also if you're on the same machine, remove the host completely from your urls, so url should be `url: '/data',`

Comment: Response Header : Content-Type:"application/json; charset=utf-8"  Content-Length:"65"                                                 Request Header : Accept:"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" and GET method. I am using mozilla and used its developer tools.

Comment: Okay, to back up a second. If you're doing all of this on the same host then you don't need CORS. If your dev web server and dev web client are on different hosts you need CORS. CORS is working correctly when the server responds with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header. What I would do now is try the "hello world" example from the flask CORS package.

Comment: now my client and server both are on the same host. so I donot need CORS and still I am suffering with nothing on the web browser. Can anyone provide a small working example "hello_world" demo simulating my code snippet? That would be a great help.

Comment: At this point you should ask a new question. I believe my answer on CORS is correct.

Comment: I will ask a new question with the modified code. Thanks